# category wise report in single page

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a table like below image
[image]

I wank to create a report like following image
[image]

I have created three formula field for filter Banana, Potato and Corn. Formula code is here:

if {Table1.Purpose}='Banana' then
    {Table1.LoanAmount}
else
    0

if {Table1.Purpose}='Potato' then
    {Table1.LoanAmount}
else
    0

if {Table1.Purpose}='Corn' then
    {Table1.LoanAmount}
else
    0

I also created three formula field to sum Banana, Potato, Corn. Formula name is SBanana, SPotato, SCorn

```
sum({@Banana}), sum({@Potato}), sum({@Corn})
```

And i insert it in my crystal report. But my report not show like this image. It shows four pages for four records. How can i create report like above image?

Answer (score 0):

Insert 3 CrossTabs in the Report Footer a, b, and c, each with a different element controlling the row.

Another (more complex) option is to use subreports.

Comment: Tell me details please